Extending a TypeScript type by adding new element in the array of a field
I want to tell TS that the type is as it expects with only a slight alteration of adding a field. The trick is that I don't need to add the field to the type itself but to the set of available elements in the collection of one of its fields.
This works but is verbose and clunky.
const explicit = this.element.nativeElement.attributes.banana;

I could improve readability.
const pre = this.element.nativeElement;
const implicit = pre.attributes.banana;

In fact, I already have such field. However, due to other considerations, it's typed as follows, making it bark at me due to incorrect typing.
const typed = this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
const boohoo = typed.attributes.banana;

Naturally, I could cheat. But writing TS and using any is like getting a flashlight and making it driven by solar energy.
const typed = this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
const weehee = (typed.attributes as any).banana;

That's why I want to say, hey TS, lets add a new field like as HTMLElement & { banana: string } but in such a way that the banana becomes a part of the attributes and not the element itself.
const retyped = this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement & { ??? };

I can't figure out how and I've tried going through all the examples I could find. I know it's possible, because it's weirdly coherent. I can't see how, other than declaring a new type explicitly. And without cheating.

what's wrong with HTMLElement & { attributes: {banana : string } } ?

Please [edit] the question to be a [mre] we can all copy and paste into our IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now you're using this without the requisite context. Maybe the existing suggestions and answer are what you're looking for, but if not, it would really help to have more clarity in the question.

@AlexanderNenashev There's almost nothing wrong with it. The only thing wrong with it is that I was too dense to figure it out myself. (I was horsing around with arrays and recreating collection etc.) Feel free, welcome and urged to post that as an excellent answer to my question so I can accept it. Thank you so much.

You could extend your cast type like that:
HTMLElement & { attributes: { banana : string } } 


I'm not sure what you want to achieve by doing this, but I guess this is what you want:
interface CustomNamedNodeMap extends NamedNodeMap {
  banana: string;
}

interface CustomHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
  attributes: CustomNamedNodeMap;
}

(this.element.nativeElement as CustomHTMLElement).attributes.banana;


Thanks for the attempt. Unfortunately, I don't want to create a new type (it's implied in the last paragraph but, admittedly, not very apparent). I'm looking for something like you can see in the first comment. Perhaps you want to snatch it and use that in your answer. (I sense that the commenter may be too busy to post it themselves, so we're good.) Keep your original answer as well - it may come in handy for future readers.
